# What does ?: mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I found this piece of code:

```
std::string(avdInfo_getSystemImagePath(m_avd)
                                ?: avdInfo_getSystemInitImagePath(m_avd))
```

I only found information about the conditional operator: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/

That is, ? and : are separated. But what does it mean when they are together? both `avdInfo_getSystemImagePath` and `avdInfo_getSystemInitImagePath` return `char*`

Answer (score 7):

It's a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

```
x ?: y
```

is the same as

```
x ? x : y
```

Except that `x` will only be evaluated once.